# Three Overlapping <span>s

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have 3 `<span>`s overlap so one is on the left, one on the right and one is 100% the width within a `<div>`?

It should look like this:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
#1 {
    float: left;
}

#2 {
    float: right;
}

#3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This causes one thing to move down though:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the two on the sides (1 & 2) to be fixed-width, and the one in the middle (3) to fill the remaining space, or can they all three be fixed-with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and most flexible would be to add the spans to a container. You can add `position: absolute` to the spans. The spans can be positioned inside their container by adding `position: relative` to the container.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="span1">1</span>
  <span class="span2">2</span>
  <span class="span3">3</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px; /* Just to prove that the spans obey this */
    background-color: blue; /* Will be covered by span3*/
    position: relative; /* Allows positioning of spans inside container*/
}
span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2em; /* Just add some body to them */
}
.span1 {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /* This one is on the left (overlapping span3) */
    top:0;
}
.span2 {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* This one is on the right (overlapping span3) */
    top:0;
}
.span3 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center; /* This span is full width, so center the text in it */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2ppS/1/

Note that `span3` is actually 100% of the (inner) width of the container div. `span1` and `span2` are overlapping `span3`. This seems to be exactly what you're asking for, but know that contents of span3 might be obscured by the other spans.

Comment: This is very close to what I want. The problem is that `<div>` 2 disappears for some reason.

Comment: Div 2? There is only one div. That one doesn't disappear, but it happens to be completely covered by span3. I guess I don't fully understand your issue.

Comment: My apologies `<span>` 2 disappears not the `<div>`.

Comment: Really? Not in my browser (Chrome). But notice I gave the container a fixed width of 500px. Maybe your screen has a lower resolution than mine, and span2 disappears out of the screen on the right in JSFiddle on your PC. What happens when I make it smaller? : http://jsfiddle.net/g2ppS/2/

Comment: The strange thing is your code works fine in fiddle, but when I add it to my project it doesn't work.

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe you've got some other CSS that messes it up. The best way is to find those elements in the browser's developer tools ('Inspect element'), and check it's style. It's near impossible to guess what is going wrong if it works in a test situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach this result using CSS floating
`float:left` and `float:right`

Example:

```
#span1{
float:left;
}
#span2{
float:right;
}
```

And to make it stretch to 100% width as you wanted:

```
span{
display:block;
}
#div3{
width:100%; /* this is default */
display:block; /* also default */
}
```

With the HTML

```
<div id='div3'><span id='span1'></span><span id='span2'></span></div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but I end up getting one moved to the next line.

Comment: @cab Give exact % or px values.

Comment: I want `<div>` 3 to be 100% the width.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but you forgot about the 3rd `<span>`

Comment: Because you wrote "I want <div> 3 to be 100% the width." Since there was only 1 div, I assumed the div with id "3" existed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/y34yH/)**

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child1"></span>
    <span class="child2"></span>
</span>
```

---

```
.parent{
    display:block;
    background-color:#eee;
    height:30px;
}
.child1,.child2{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:red;
    height:30px;
}
.child2{
    float:right;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Works, but `display:inline-block` seems to have no additional effect (seems to be obsolete). Also, there is no span 3 inbetween.